# How to keep model attributes in a common place where more than one controllers can use it

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring framework. Can anyone resolve the below issue.

I have too many model attribute methodes(@ModelAttribute) in a controller say A, now I want to use all these model attributes in other controllers but  I donot want to extend controller A,  so there any way to keep all these model attributes in common place where all the controllers can execute this on each call.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3.2 you can use the [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation to create a class with model attribute (and init binder, and exception handler) methods that [apply to all controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

In older versions, instead of extending controller A, cannot you move the annotated methods to a new class and make it the parent of all the controller classes?

Comment: @ControllerAdvice will not be applied to specific controllers(if I'm not wrong), it will be applied to all the controllers. Secondly, extending a class is also an option but I was thinking of the other way out.

Comment: @Tarun Yes, that's true. `@ControllerAdvice` will not help if you want only some controllers in the same context to use the model attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize interceptors to achieve this. Interceptor has access to `ModelAndView`, so you should just put what you need to model, in one of appropriate methods provided by interceptor.

More details:

- [Using Spring Interceptors in your MVC Webapp](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-interceptors-your)
- [Spring MVC handler interceptors example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used this approach but in this we have modelAndView object in the post method only, and in my case I want the model object in pre method. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With spring 3.2 we have the option to specify the basepackage where we want to intercept with @ControllerAdvice. Below is the link

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are having a common model attribute method and a common model attribute bean.
If the spring you are using is having an old version then the least you can do is separate out the body of the method in a common utility.

The other solution is inheritance , you can create a super controller that has one model attribute and then extend that controller for actual implementations that you want. Keep common functionality in super controller and specific implementations in child classes.